# Using Events Delegates in multi tenant web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, event-handling

I'm developing a multi tenant n-tier web application using asp.net Mvc 5.

In my service layer I am defining custom events for every important action and raising these events once these actions are executed. For example

```
Public event EventHandler EntityCreated;

Public void Create(Entity item) {
  Save(item);
  ......
  EntityCreated(this, item);
}
```

I intend on hooking up business rules and notifications to these events. The main reason I want to use events is decoupling of the logic and easy plug-ability of more events handlers without modifying my service layer.

**Question:**
Does it make sense using events and delegates in asp.net?

Most examples I find online are for win forms or wpf. I get the advantage when it comes to multithreaded applications. Also the **events are defined once per form** and are active for the lifetime of the form.

But in my case the **events will be per http request**. So is it an overhead defining these events?

Comment: it sounds like you need a pub-sub system. these won't do it for you.

Comment: If they're useful to you in your application then use them.  If they're not, then don't.  Without knowing anything about your application, we couldn't possibly tell you if they would be useful or not.

Comment: @Yash Who subscribe those events? Do you plan to notify all other browsers if a new entity is created?

Comment: @win I will have a EventHandlerService which will subscribe to these events. as of now I want to notify users assigned to the entity via email and/or signalr. Going forward some of these events will need to perform some workflow or automation in the application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have implemented Udi Dahan's implementation as pointed out by @Imran but with a few changes.

My Events are being raised in a Service Layer and for that using a Static Class dint seem right. Also have added support for async/await.

Also going down the Events & Delegates path did work out but it just felt like an overhead to register the events per request.

I have blogged my solution here http://www.teknorix.com/event-driven-programming-in-asp-net

Answer (score 2):

As others pointed out that pub/sub or event bus is one solution. Another solution is something like what you are trying to do here but make it more formal.

Let's take a specific example of creating a customer. You want to send a welcome email when a new customer is created in the application. The domain should only be concerned with creating the customer and saving it in the db and not all the other details such as sending emails. So you add a CustomerCreated event. These types of events are called Domain Event as opposed to user interface events such as button click etc.

When the CustomerCreated event is raised, it should be handled somewhere in the code so that it can do the needful. You can use an EventHandlerService as you mentioned (but this can soon becomes concerned with too many events) or use the pattern that [Udi Dahan](http://www.udidahan.com/2009/06/14/domain-events-salvation/) talks about. I have successfully used Udi's method with many DI Containers and the beauty of the pattern is that your classes remain SRP compliant. You just have to implement a particular interface and registration code at the application bootstrap time using reflection.

If you need further help with this topic, let me know and I can share with you the code snippets to make it work.

Comment: So this is just a pattern without the use of events or delegates? Any reason why not to use c# events? As you said i do intend on splitting the EventHandlerService into smaller classes that will deal with just one domain service for eg CustomerService will expose the events, and CustomerServiceEventHandler will subscribe to these events.

Comment: Well, you can of course use events as you are trying to do. My point was that I have used the above mentioned pattern in production applications successfully and it supports the use of dependency injection in individual handler classes hence making them easy to unit test. If you can overcome the hurdles in whatever pattern you are trying, then that should of course be your first choice. If not, you at least have a good alternative.

Comment: As far as dependency injection goes i am sure i can get it to work with my approach. I would like to know more about how good or bad my approach is. I have not seen many examples of using events and delegates in asp.net so was concerned. Is it a very big overhead registering the events per request lifecycle ? Is there a way to register them once per application startup ?

Comment: Hey @Imran, i'd appreciate if you can share some code snippets on how you are using this pub-sub method suggested by Udi Dahan. Also did you manage to get it to work with async/await ?

Comment: I've tried implementing this and its failing with IOC. I'm using Autofac as my IOC Container. Struggling with trying to inject IContainer into the DomainEvents static class.